# How to solve a non-convex programming problem?

Tags: combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, programming, semidefinite-programming

Let $A$ and $C\ $ be $n\times n$ symmetric matrices, and $A\bullet C=Tr(A^TC)$. Let $S\subseteq [n]\times [n]\times [n]$. Define a non-convex programming problem as follows.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\max\ \ \ C\bullet X\\
&\text{ s.t.} \ \ \ \ \  A\bullet X=1,\\
&\qquad \quad X_{i,j}X_{i,k}=0, \ \ \forall\ (i,j,k)\in S,\\
&\qquad \quad X\succeq 0,\ X\geq 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a variable ranging over the set of $n\times n\ $ symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, $\ X\succeq 0$ means $X$ is positive semi-definite, $\ X\geq 0$ means each entry of $X$ is nonnegative, and $X_{i,j}$ is the $(i,j)$-entry of $X$.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? And how to consider its dual problem? Thank you.

Comment: You could model the product constraint as a mixed-integer SDP.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Could you please tell me how to do it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Well $xy=0,\ x,y\geq 0$ is the same as $0\leq x\leq Mz$, $0\leq y\leq M(1-z)$ where $z$ is a binary variable and $M$ is an upper bound on $x,y$. See https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#boolean-operators But there is not a load of MISDP solvers, if any. YALMIP can model it I think. But then it is possible that YALMIP can model your whole problem directly.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you so much. If I write the problem as a MISDP, is it the case that the optimal value of MISDP is the same with the optimal value of its dual MISDD? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what a dual of a mixed-integer problem is.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Do you mean there is no general way to derive the dual problem of a MISDP? Also do you know how to derive the dual of my original problem? Thanks a lot.